# Saving Image in NodeJs server side

Tags: node.js

I am trying to save an image in a public folder in my server, I am sending a base64 image and when it gets there I decode that and try to save in a specific folder inside the server. The image is arriving and everything works fine but saving the image in the folder. My server folders are as follow:

[image: Folders in the server]

In the js file I try to save using the following path:

```
const path = `/home/apps_nodejs/procurala/imagens/${objeto.nome}.png`;

    if(objeto.img != undefined){
        let bitmap = new Buffer(objeto.img, 'base64');
        fs.writeFileSync(path, bitmap);
    }
```

But in my server log I keep catching this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './procurala/imagens/Gjfu.png'
0|app      |     at Error (native)
0|app      |     at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
0|app      |     at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1347:33)
0|app      |     at salvar (/home/procurala/apps_nodejs/procurala/config/app/infra/eventosBanco.js:31:16)
0|app      |     at /home/procurala/apps_nodejs/procurala/config/app/routes/evento.js:76:19
0|app      |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/procurala/apps_nodejs/procurala/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
0|app      |     at next (/home/procurala/apps_nodejs/procurala/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
0|app      |     at Route.dispatch (/home/procurala/apps_nodejs/procurala/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
0|app      |     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/procurala/apps_nodejs/procurala/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
0|app      |     at /home/procurala/apps_nodejs/procurala/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

I know that I am missing some point at the path... but I really don't know how would be the right way of setting the path!

Thanks in advance, guys

Comment: Try relative path, e.g., if you source is in apps_nodejs, save as `./procurala/imagens/{name}.png`.
Btw, your server is running on Linux system?

Comment: Based on the screenshot, it looks like your path is `/apps_nodejs/...` instead of `/home/apps_nodejs/...`.

Comment: Yeah, it is running on Linux, I am connecting with that by using SSH. I did that but I keep having the error, I am going to edit the question with the full error log

Comment: I tried this one now and the error appeared again: const path = `./procurala/imagens/${objeto.nome}.png`;

Comment: By the way, thank you all for helping me

Comment: If you are sure that the file exists in the folder, you might want to consider using the path library in nodejs.

Comment: It looks like the desired path should be `\`/apps_nodejs/procurala/imagens/${objeto.nome}.png\``